# How to change the DateCreated on a StorageFile?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.datecreated.aspx , StorageFile.DateCreated is read-only.

On the desktop, I can do:

```
IStorageFile file = ...
DateTime date = ...
BasicProperties props = await file.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
var changes = new List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>();
changes.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, object>("System.DateCreated", date));
await props.SavePropertiesAsync(changes);
```

but on WP8, BasicProperties.SavePropertiesAsync isn't implemented.

Is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to take the date created and use [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) to store the file path and the date created. The risk being that you have to make sure the value is updated everytime you create a file.

Otherwise you could use [moveAndReplaceAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh738483.aspx) to move the file and reset the date created.

You could also store the values in your own secondary file or database, but that would require extra IO on every file read. (You have to open two files to get at the file contents and the 'date created').